# Quiero publicar dos gadgets (divs) uno al lado del otro

Tags: div

necesito si me pueden ayudar y explicar un poco como hacer que estos divs esten alineados uno al lado del otro. Cuando lo pongo tal cual asi se pone el gadget arriba y el otro abajo y yo quiero que este uno al lado del otro.
Desde ya, muchas gracias por la colaboración.
Connie

```
    <iframe src="https://www.losarcanos.com/webservice/horoscope1.php?t=1" width="490" height="300" scrolling=no marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 frameborder=0 border=0 style="border:0;margin:0;padding:0;"></iframe><br />
```

Horoscopo

---

```
    <iframe src="https://www.losarcanos.com/webservice/horoscope1.php?t=1" width="490" height="300" scrolling=no marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 frameborder=0 border=0 style="border:0;margin:0;padding:0;"></iframe><br />
```

Horoscopo

Comment: Sólo estás compartiendo un iframe, revisa que el código que has incluido se corresponde con aquello que estás preguntando (alinear dos divs).

Comment: Hola Connie, bienvenida, para poder aydarte, necesitamos ver el código de tu aplicación, al menos la sección relevante que te ocasiona problemas, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!